# When somebody is creating bad back links to my site from forums in other languages, what should I do to prevent SEO problems?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, backlinks, blackhat

I have a site and somebody is creating bad back links in different types of forum sites.   They are creating new links every day using comments and signatures.  The sites with these back links aren't relevant to my site or products. They don't often even match the language of my website (English).  The bad links sites are usually Japanese, Chinese and Korean.

Is  this type of technique harmful for my site as negative SEO?  Is Google likely  give me a penalty?  Does it matter that these sites aren't relevant to my content, language, or products?

I have been submitting these types of web sites to Google Disavow tools. Is the disavow process the right thing to be doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already answer your question, yes use Google Disavow tool when bad links point to you.

Actually there are two scenario

1. Google can ignore your link, If you're getting link from pure spam (link farm) website. Google is pretty good on that, because many good webmaster don't check their backlink profile all the time.
2. Use disavow tool, If you think someone building low quality or pure spam link against you. I suggest to use this tool, when your site is very new, because you don't have strong link profile.

But if your site have too many good natural backlinks and someone doing negative SEO against you, then it will impact ZERO. Yes zero, it means if someone spam wikipedia with dozens of bad link, then it will impact ZERO. **Google always check your full link profile before they penalize you.**  When you disavow any link or whole domain, then Google simply don't consider it those links on their calculation. [Refer this post from Google Webmaster Blog](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2012/10/a-new-tool-to-disavow-links.html) it has solid information about this tool. To block whole domain use

```
domain: badsite.cn
domain: badsite.jp
```

Comment: I'd caution against preemptive link disavowals. Google's own guidance stresses the Disavow tool should be used only if you're "confident that the links are causing issues for you". And generally, if they're causing a problem, there'll be a notification in Search Console.